# I am getting Weird output in console when fetching Data from Database

Tags: spring-data-jpa, h2

I am trying to fetch some data ,I am using H2 data base. The model is

```
@Entity
public class Employee {
    
    @Id
    private long empid;
    private String empname;
    private Date empdoj;
    private double emptotalsalary;
    private String emptype;
```

The service class is Where I used the methods

```
@Autowired
EmployeeRepository repo;
public int countAllEmployees() {
        return (int)repo.count();
    }
    
    public List<Employee> getPermanentEmployees(String employeetype){
        Employee filter = new Employee();
        filter.setEmptype(employeetype);
        Example<Employee> example = Example.of(filter);
        List<Employee> emplist = (List<Employee>)repo.findAll();
        return emplist;
    }
    
    
    public List<Employee> getEmployeeNames(){
        Employee filter  = new Employee();
        filter.setEmpname("tha");
        ExampleMatcher matcher = ExampleMatcher.matching().withStringMatcher(StringMatcher.CONTAINING).withIgnoreCase();
        Example<Employee> example = Example.of(filter,matcher);
        return (List<Employee>)repo.findAll();
    }
```

In Console I am getting this output

```
Employee Count
5
Get List of permanent Employees
[com.example.demo.Employee@416c1b0, com.example.demo.Employee@a302f30, com.example.demo.Employee@4af44f2a, com.example.demo.Employee@47994b51, com.example.demo.Employee@143fe09c]
Get List of all Employees Ending with Tha
com.example.demo.Employee@416c1b0
com.example.demo.Employee@a302f30
com.example.demo.Employee@4af44f2a
com.example.demo.Employee@47994b51
com.example.demo.Employee@143fe09c
```

I dont understand why this is coming.please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suppose by weird you mean the text like `com.example.demo.Employee@143fe09c`

Somewhere in your code, you are printing the Employee records. eg: `System.out.println(employee)` `System.out.println` uses the object's toString() method to print the object. Since you did not provide it in your Employee class it uses the toString method from superclass of Employee which is Object.

As mentioned in the doc, it prints the classname followed by @ and the hash.
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#toString--

> Returns a string representation of the object. In general, the
> toString method returns a string that "textually represents" this
> object. The result should be a concise but informative representation
> that is easy for a person to read. It is recommended that all
> subclasses override this method.
>
> The toString method for class Object returns a string consisting of
> the name of the class of which the object is an instance, the at-sign
> character `@', and the unsigned hexadecimal representation of the hash
> code of the object. In other words, this method returns a string equal
> to the value of:
>
> ```
>  getClass().getName() + '@' + Integer.toHexString(hashCode())
> ```

Just override the toString method in Employee class to generate text representation of the Employee object. Your IDE already provides a nice way to generate this method.

```
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Employee{" + "empid=" + empid +
                ", empname=" + empname + "'" +
                '}';
    }
```